# Integrating MySQL Community Server 5.6 into Netbeans 7

Tags: mysql, windows, netbeans-7

I have just installed the MySQL community Server 5.6 in my Windows 7 laptop using the msi installer.
Now I want to integrate the server into my Netbeans 7 IDE.

From the Netbeans tutorials
[here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html#configuring) ,
there is a field in the admin property dialogue box that requires the Path/URL to Admin tool.
But looks like I am unable to find the admin tool.

From this [tutorials](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/setup-dev-environ.html#communicate)  ,
it is stated that the admin tool is included in the  MySQL GUI Tools bundle.

However , from this
[page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)
it's been mentioned that the MySQL GUI Tool bundle is replaced by the MySQL WorkBench.
But i'm still not able to get the **Admin tool**  from the MySQL Workbench.

Can someone help me find the admin tool or is there another way to do the integration?

Comment: I am trying to navigate to the service tab but was unable. Can u please explain further.

Comment: The window locations are all customizable. If you are using a default setting, the west panel is an explorer (project explorer, file explorer, ...). There will be tabs on the top of this west panel for these views. One should be "Services". If you don't see the tab, select "Window -> Services" from the menu and it should appear. Once the tab is selected, the contents will have a tree layout from which the "Databases" node should be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the location of the Admin tool for the MySQL Workbench. The solution was presented in this  [article](http://javawebaction.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-register-mysql-database-server.html)

This URL below gives the general location in the admin tool in the Workbench folder

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47\MySQLWorkbench.exe
```

Filling the Path/URL to Admin tool with the above file does work for me hope, it works for you too.